# How to allocate array of pointers for strings by malloc in C?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I have this struct in C
Example:

```
typedef struct 
{
    const char * array_pointers_of_strings [ 30 ];
    // etc.
} message;
```

I need copy this array_pointers_of_strings to new array for sort strings. I need only copy adress.

```
while ( i < 30 )
{
   new_array [i] = new_message->array_pointers_of_strings [i]; 
   // I need only copy adress of strings
}
```

My question is: How to allocate new_array [i] by malloc() for only adress of strings?

Answer (score 19):

As I can understand from your assignment statement in while loop I think you need array of strings instead:

```
char** new_array;
new_array = malloc(30 * sizeof(char*)); // ignore casting malloc
```

Note: By doing `=` in while loop as below:

```
new_array [i] = new_message->array_pointers_of_strings [i];
```

you are just assigning address of string (its not deep copy), but because you are also writing "*only address of strings*" so I think this is what you wants.

**Edit:**    waring *"assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type"*

you are getting this warning because you are assigning a `const char*` to `char*`  that would violate the rules of const-correctness.

You should declare your new_array like:

```
const  char** new_array;
```

*or* remove `const` in declaration of 'array_pointers_of_strings' from message stricture.

Comment: Yes, I need this but something on line new_array [i] = new_message->array_pointers_of_strings [i]; is wrong O_o My compilator gcc write me this warning: assgiment discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Comment: What if I user a double variable instead of 30 in `malloc(30 * sizeof(char*))`? Then `new_array [i]` syntax won't work. How do you access the element then?

Answer (score 7):

This:

```
char** p = malloc(30 * sizeof(char*));
```

will allocate a buffer big enough to hold 30 pointers to `char` (or string pointers, if you will) and assign to `p` its address.

`p[0]` is pointer 0, `p[1]` is pointer 1, ..., `p[29]` is pointer 29.

---

Old answer...

If I understand the question correctly, you can either create a fixed number of them by simply declaring variables of the type `message`:

```
message msg1, msg2, ...;
```

or you can allocate them dynamically:

```
message *pmsg1 = malloc(sizeof(message)), *pmsg2 = malloc(sizeof(message)), ...;
```

Comment: No. I have pointer new_message with array of pointers of strings. I need allocate char array for thirty adress strings by malloc. I dont know how to allocate new_array for copy adress of strings...

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_LEN 2
typedef struct
{
    char * string_array [ ARRAY_LEN ];
} message;

int main() {
    int i;
    message message;
    message.string_array[0] = "hello";
    message.string_array[1] = "world";
    for (i=0; i < ARRAY_LEN; ++i ) {
        printf("%d %s\n",i, message.string_array[i]);
    }

    char ** new_message = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*) * ARRAY_LEN);
    for (i=0; i < ARRAY_LEN; ++i ) {
        new_message[i] = message.string_array[i];
    }
    for (i=0; i < ARRAY_LEN; ++i ) {
        printf("%d %s\n",i, new_message[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

is it mandatory for you to use Malloc? Because Calloc is the function in the C Standard Library which will make the job:

> *"The calloc() function allocates memory for an array of nmemb elements of size bytes each and returns a pointer to the allocated memory"*. (Source: [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc))

I'm just creating a hash table and it has an array of pointers to nodes, and a easy way to do it is this:

```
hash_table_t *hash_table_create(unsigned long int size){
hash_table_t *ptr = NULL;

ptr = malloc(sizeof(hash_table_t) * 1);
if (ptr == NULL)
    return (NULL);

ptr->array = calloc(size, sizeof(hash_node_t *)); #HERE
if (ptr->array == NULL)
    return (NULL);
ptr->size = size;
return (ptr);}
```

Hope it works for you guys!

[calloc](/questions/tagged/calloc) [c](/questions/tagged/c)