# Strcpy string in array of strings segmentation fault

Tags: arrays, c, string

I want to make an array of strings where each string is one line from a text file. When i do strcpy(stringList[lineCount], lineBuf) I get segmentation fault and don't know why.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAXLINELENGTH 20
#define MAXLINES 10

int fileToStringList(char* fileName, char** stringList){
    char* lineBuf = (char*) malloc(MAXLINELENGTH);
    size_t lineBufSize = 0;
    int lineCount = 0;
    ssize_t lineSize;
    FILE* fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if(!fp){
        printf("Error reading file");
        exit(1);    
    }

    lineSize = getline(&lineBuf, &lineBufSize, fp);
    while(lineSize >= 0){
        strcpy(stringList[lineCount], lineBuf);//segmentation fault
        lineCount++;
        lineSize = getline(&lineBuf, &lineBufSize, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return lineCount;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char* fileName = argv[2];
    char** stringList = (char**) malloc(MAXLINES);
    int lineCount;
    lineCount = fileToStringList(fileName, stringList);
    printf("Number of lines: %d\n", lineCount);
}
```

Comment: I can guess it's because of "(char**) malloc(MAXLINES)". Try to look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686890/how-to-allocate-array-of-pointers-for-strings-by-malloc-in-c

Comment: The correct syntax for `malloc` is `Type *variable = malloc(NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS * sizeof *variable);`, where `Type` is the type of the elements, in your case `char *` or `char`.

Comment: The problem isn't so much the malloc itself as the fact that `stringList[n]` is not initialized. It should be set to point at allocated memory before calling strcpy.

Comment: @Oscar Stenqvist, What should happen if the line is longer than `MAXLINELENGTH`?

Answer (score 0):

At least these issues:

**Uninitialized value**

`stringList[lineCount]` not yet assigned.  `strcpy()` is receiving a junk destination pointer.  Allocate first, use `strdup` or use `lineBuf`.

```
// strcpy(stringList[lineCount], lineBuf);
stringList[lineCount] = strdup(lineBuf);

// or "take" lineBuf
stringList[lineCount] = lineBuf;
lineBuf = NULL;
lineBufSize = 0;
```

**Add limit**

```
// while(lineSize >= 0){
while(lineSize >= 0 && lineCount < MAXLINES){
```

**Unneeded allocation**

`getline()` allocates as needed.  Cast not needed.  Likely off by 1 and `MAXLINELENGTH + 1` was needed.

```
// char* lineBuf = (char*) malloc(MAXLINELENGTH);
char* lineBuf = NULL;
```

**Missing `free()`**

`fileToStringList()` fails to free `lineBuf`.

**Wrong size and unnecessary cast**

```
// char** stringList = (char**) malloc(MAXLINES);
char** stringList = malloc(sizeof stringList[0] * MAXLINES);
```

---

Example re-write:

```
for (lineCount = 0; lineCount < MAXLINES; lineCount++) { 
  stringList[lineCount] = NULL;
  size_t lineBufSize = 0;
  if (getline(&stringList[lineCount], &lineBufSize, fp)) < 0) {
    break;
  }
}
```